# Programmatic check for img src in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a page with many customer logos on it in a table. One table cell tries to get the logo like this:

```
<TableCell className={classNames(classes.urlDealCell, classes.dealCell)}>
    {this.getLogo(deal.CompanyWebsite)}
</TableCell>
```

`getLogo` is:

```
getLogo = url => {
  const source = `https://logo.clearbit.com/${url}`;
  return <img src={source} width="30" />;
};
```

80% of the time, the logo comes back fine, and if there is no `deal.CompanyWebsite`, I can provide a default logo. But I need to handle another edge case:

If the request to the img source fails with a URL like this:
https://logo.clearbit.com/absoluteGarbage, can I somehow check this in React and fallback to the default logo?

Must I try a GET request to the src URL for each logo *before* trying to assign the `src` attribute of the `img`? If so, this would double the number of image requests, which would suck for larger page result sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <img src={someurl} 
   onError={(e)=>{e.target.onerror = null; e.target.src="image_path_here"}}/>
```

When an image fails to load, onError gets called. Use this function to do your logic

Comment: Thanks, haven't used that before

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`onError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/image#a-onerror) attribute:

```
<img src="https://logo.clearbit.com/absoluteGarbage"
     onError={event => event.target.src=defaultUrl} />
```

**JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g1wubsLm/1/**